# Issue with clicking download button with chromedriver python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automatically download a file from macrotrends with selenium/chrome driver(phantomJS when I get this working). I just realized that the download button I am clicking is in an iframe, so I tried switching to the iframe and then clicking the button, but I am still getting a NoSuchElementException. Also, do the drivers have any built in functionality I could use to not spam enter sends and not have to use time.sleep?

```
class get_price_data:
def __init__(self, name): 
    price_driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="jqxInput"]').send_keys(name)
    while(price_driver.current_url=='https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AMZN/amazon/stock-price-history'):
        price_driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="jqxInput"]').send_keys(u'\ue007')
    time.sleep(5)
    price_driver.switch_to_frame('chart_iframe')
    time.sleep(5)
    price_driver.find_element_by_class_name(r'dataExport chart_buttons btn btn-danger btn-xs')
    price_driver.click()
```

TESLA=get_price_data('TSLA')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on `Download Data` which is inside an iframe.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()` and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(price_driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"chart_iframe")))
WebDriverWait(price_driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".dataExport.chart_buttons.btn.btn-danger.btn-xs"))).click()
```

Or Use below xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(price_driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"chart_iframe")))
WebDriverWait(price_driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Download Data')]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Link to understand [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector doesn't work here...

try replacing this:

```
price_driver.find_element_by_class_name(r'dataExport chart_buttons btn btn-danger btn-xs')
```

with this:

```
price_driver.find_element_by_class_name('div>button.dataExport')
```